# Bootstrap columns display stacked inside of a row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

My columns are displaying on top of each other in the same row. Their columns add up to 12.

[image]

HTML:

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="content row">        
        <section class="main col col-sm-8">
                <h2>main content</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </section>  <!-- col-lg-8 -->
        <section class="sidebar col col-sm-4">
                <h2>SIDEBAR</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </section> <!--  col-lg-4 -->
  </div>      <!-- row -->
</section>    <!-- container -->
```

Comment: Please clarify, what is the question here?

Comment: Are you sure you have referenced the Bootstrap libraries, and are you using Bootstrap v3 or v2? Because as the code stands above, it works fine http://www.bootply.com/tyNE4zd7aU

Comment: so, what's your question?

Comment: Bootstrap version used is 3. It's properly imported as <link rel="stylesheet" src="bootstrap.min.css" media="screen"> in the head.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can use section tags, you need to use divs. What's that content class for? Something custom? Here's the basic layout

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <h2>main content</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>Sidebar</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I alternate divs with sections to make html more readable. I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: Well I would test it at least, there is no use of sections in the bootstrap docs. The other issue might be all those other classes you had added in there. What were those for?

Comment: These are all bootstrap classes belonging to the grid system. Nothing unusual. I got another problem as well. If you go to chat with me and check it out I'm going to upvote you.

Comment: I've never seen a bootstrap class called content, main or column and I've written a book on bootstrap, might want to check your class names

Comment: h2 element? You have it applied to the div tag. That class is not part of Bootstrap. Do you have custom styles attached to those classes? They may be causing your problems if it isn't your html syntax, which I suspect it is

Comment: Those other classes are not targeted with CSS at all. What's wrong with adding an additional class to the bootstrap one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64446/discussion-between-nosille-and-matt-lambert).

Comment: nothing if there are no styles applied to them. However, makes it a bit harder to read IMHO. If no custom styles are applied then it's definitely your HTML syntax. try it without section tags

Comment: Bootstrap grid classes work just fine on HTML5 block elements like `<section>`.

Comment: @cvrebert you might very well be right, I've never actually tried it, however, if he has no custom css then it has to be a problem with his HTML somewhere

Answer (score -1):

i don't think there is main or sidebar classes in bootstrap

you maybe did some styling that affected the default bootstrap behavior the code you added should add to

columns when having enough width